# Saving a Plot as a PDF without the " Out[.] " Appearing in the Plot?

Tags: export

I suddenly cannot save a ListLinePlot (with a legend) as a PDF without it also saving the indicator "Out[.] =" also there. This is really strange since I've been saving them all along (by highlighting the cell and using "save selection as" without it showing, then suddenly out of nowhere, this "Out[.]=" started appearing? I never even closed the notebook. Could it maybe have something to do with having done a Clear["Global`*"]?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Perhaps try restarting with a new kernel? Please also add a minimal working example to your question so that others can test to see if they can help you solve the problem.

Comment: You can delete the  `Out` manually.

Comment: right click ON the graph and then save. Or use `Export`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann , deleting manually worked perfectly the first time, when Out was showing. Now Out doesn't show on any of them, but shows in the PDF again?

Comment: @Moose mysterious!

Comment: @C.E., yes the answers that we have gotten here are also there. I would have said that the focus of my question was different then just "how to...," but "why suddenly the change...." I realize that maybe this is unanswerable and all that matters is the "how..." Since the rules of duplicates for this site asks "If the answers there do not address your problem,..." which they don't specifically, but maybe close enough. Before I mark it as answered by your referred question thread, why can't I find it when searching "how to save both plot and legend together"? Does it really need "can" that bad?

Comment: @Moose Stack Exchange's search engine is not good. If you search for "save plot and legend together mathematica", you'll find it. I agree with what you say about the difference between the two questions. I suggested closing it as a duplicate because the answers that we can give will probably be the same. It's a "functional equivalent" of the other question, if you will, even if not exactly the same. And I think marking it as a duplicate may help people having this issue finding the larger number of answers over there.

Answer (score 2):

Simply right-click the plot and choose Save Graphics As...  *Do not select its cell bracket and use Save Selection As...!* Just right click *the plot itself* without selecting anything.

If the plot has a legend, select both the plot and the legend with the mouse, as if they were text. Make sure that the cell bracket is not selected. Now right-click and use Save Selection As...

---

As an alternative to both, use [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) instead of the GUI method.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is also a legend that I would like to save with it.

Comment: @Moose Then select the plot and the legend, as if you were selecting text with the mouse. Make sure you are not selecting the cell bracket.

Comment: that worked. Thanks so much.